# Windows doesn't hibernate properly after migrating to ssd

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, hibernate, migration

I got a new SSD drive and migrated the system on it, it boots just fine, but I'm having a problem with hibernating the laptop.
It after reopening the laptop, it doesn't reopen the application that was opened before the hibernation.

Also, I tried to delete the system partition (E:) from the HDD drive, but I couldn't, the delete option is disabled for that partition.

Any idea what's wrong?

[Screen shot of disk manger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8FnK.png)

Comment: Is it correct that your page file is on E:?

Comment: @DavidMarshall E was the partition that the windows used to be on (on the HDD), i don't know why is it still the page file partition.

Comment: Check in Advanced System Settings. If E: is being used, set up a Page File on C: and remove the one on E:. Restart.

Comment: You can also use `diskpart` to remove stubborn partitions. Diskpart, list disk, sel disk n, list part, sel part p, del part override. Make sure n is the HDD and p is the stubborn partition.

Comment: I was [having the same issue](https://superuser.com/q/1764007/320611), turns out the **EFI system type** was not set.  I set it to the correct GUID value and fixed my issue.